# Get the path of a dir I just created with Laravel Storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-storage

Considering this code:

```
Storage::makeDirectory('my_dir');
```

Can I get the full path of `my_dir` right after? Something like:

```
echo Storage::getFullPathOf('my_dir');
```

Or do I need to do something with `storage_path` helper?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use >= 5.2, try to use `url` method (see `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter`):

```
Storage::url('my_dir'); // default disk
```

or in custom disk:

```
Storage::disk('amazon')->url('my_dir');
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that is no way(I mean biult-in function) to acheive your goal.
I think you

> need to do something with `storage_path` helper